# Python не видит модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске кода, выдаётся ошибка:

> No module named 'requests'

Только суть в том, что `requests` установлен (проверил через `pip list`). Остальные модули вроде работают корректно. В чем проблема? Уже 30 минут бьюсь, не могу решить.
Код:

```
import requests

TOKEN = "*Скрыл*"
MAIN_URL = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}'

r = requests.get(f'{MAIN_URL}/getMe')

print(r.json())
```

```
$ pip list
Package             Version
------------------- ----------
beautifulsoup4      4.8.2
blessings           1.7
certifi             2019.11.28
cffi                1.13.2
chardet             3.0.4
colorama            0.4.3
cryptography        2.8
curtsies            0.3.1
future              0.18.2
idna                2.8
pip                 19.3.1
pycparser           2.19
pygame              1.9.6
PySocks             1.7.1
pyTelegramBotAPI    3.6.6
python-telegram-bot 12.2.0
requests            2.22.0
setuptools          41.2.0
six                 1.13.0
soupsieve           1.9.5
tornado             6.0.3
urllib3             1.25.7
wcwidth             0.1.8
```

Comment: Вы нам специально свой токен засветили?)

Comment: Да это бот для обучения, так что не особо важно)

Comment: Какая система, одна версия python установлена?

Comment: Да, только python 3.8*

Comment: Какая система (Linux/Windows/Mac)?

Comment: На Windows 7 сижу

Comment: Добавьте вывод pip list в вопрос

Comment: Добавил, 17 в списке

Comment: Вот теперь затрудняюсь. Я бы все-таки предположил, что у вас два интерпретатора, для одного requests установлен, а вторым вы запускаете скрипт.

Comment: Также возможно скрипт вы запускаете в виртуальном окружении, а requests установлен вне виртуального окружения.

Answer (score 1):

Этот модуль надо установить:

```
pip3 install requests
```

Comment: @insolor Он проверил через `pip list`, а у него python 3 -->`pip3`

Comment: Это если не Windows. А систему сначала нужно уточнить у автора вопроса, а не ломиться сразу отвечать. Принцип "самый быстрый стрелок на Диком Западе" не всегда срабатывает (очень редко).